# XSLT use concat or multiple value-of elements to join variables?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

Assume I have like 20 variables that I want to join to a csv string. Should I prefer `concat()`, or just place all variables below each other in `<xsl>` elements?

either:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat($var1, ';', ..., $var10)"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
<xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
...
<xsl:value-of select="$var10"/>
```

Especially regarding to performance, as I have hundred million rows to process.

Is the `contact` approach similar to a `java` `StringBuilder`, and the element approach similar to a `string += val` reassignment? If the, the `concat` would of course be superior. But is that true?

Comment: Personally, I don't use `concat()` when writing directly to the output. But that is mainly for code readability reasons (although I suspect performance is not improved by adding an extra calculation to the process). In any case, performance questions are processor-specific.

Comment: test will tell the truth

Comment: If you have XSLT 2 or 3 then the easiest to write that is `<xsl:value-of select="$var1, $var2, $var3" separator=";"/>`. As for performance, it will depend on the XSLT processor how it evaluates that.

Comment: I added `saxon` as tag, as it is my xslt processor. Based on saxon, can any of the approaches be more advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least I found out by profiling that `contact()` performed 25% better than multiple `xsl:text/xsl:value-of` calls. But I don't know if that can be said in general, but in my case with hundred millions of rows that's it.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely there will be a measurable performance difference, but the only way to find out is to measure it.

In Saxon a `concat()` call will always build the string in memory (until the next Saxon release...) while a series of `xsl:text`/`xsl:value-of` calls will (where possible) write it incrementally to the serializer, so that might make a difference to memory usage if the string is extremely large.